Set default PropertyGroup properties for Visual Studio projects
In Visual Studio you have many project templates.
Is it possible to set the initial PropertyGroup properties in a csproj file when a new project is created?
When I create a new console application, for example, these are the contents of its csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

If I wanted the contents of the csproj file to be different for console applications I create, how can I do that?
For instance, I want all my console application projects to have Nullable disabled by default.

The .csproj file mentioned is indeed generated by MSBuild technology, which is utilized to construct Visual Studio projects. To disable Nullable, one can insert the code directive into the PropertyGroup section of the file like this.
      <PropertyGroup>
       <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
      <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
       <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

For future projects to inherit this setting, saving the project as a template is necessary.

In Visual Studio, navigate to the menu bar and select "Project" ->
"Export Template".
In the pop-up wizard, choose "Project template" and click "Next".
Select the project you want to export, and follow the instructions in
the wizard to complete the export process.

Next time you want to create a new project：

Go to "File" -> "New" -> "Project".
In the "New Project" dialog, find your template and select it.

MSbuild and VS Template document attached below, so you can take a look at it if you need it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild?view=vs-2022
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2022

Is there a way to edit built-in templates?

comment for future readers: this answer isn't a very good one as the imported template doesn't allow for options like choosing the .NET version or using/not using top-level statements, if it is for a console application. It would be better to edit the Visual Studio built-in project template but I can't find them anywhere.

addendum to previous comment: No, the ones in E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates don't work as they are only for .Net Framework versions.

The templates for .Net Core projects are located in
C:\Program Files\dotnet\templates
they are packaged in *.nupkg files but those can be opened by archiving software (like WinRAR) and the files inside edited.
The problem is that they are per-version.
Meaning the templates for .Net 8 are used only for that version, so if you wanted to have certain property groups present in all your projects you can edit the template for the console application for .Net 8 and it will work but then you'd have to do the same thing when .Net 9 comes out.
In the end, having a custom project template and updating it seems like the only option.
BONUS:
There seems to be some ancient, eldrich flags, such as csharpFeature_Nullable that dictate whether (in this example) the Nullable property would be set in the project. However there is literally 0 information about it on the internet. Seriously.
